# Is it possible to get the rule (cinoptions) that govern the indentation for a specific line in vim

Tags: vimrc, indentation, filetype-c++

I have the following code:

```
namespace
{

template<typename T> 
    struct One // This is the odd line
{
     // impl details
}

template<typename T> 
struct Two 
{
     // impl details
}

}
```

I would want to change the indent rules to make it look like this:

```
namespace
{

template<typename T> 
struct One 
{
     // impl details
}

template<typename T> 
struct Two 
{
     // impl details
}

}
```

**Primary question** But I can't find what rule is causing the strange indentation. Is there a way to query vim for this information? (I know there is something like that in emacs)

**Secondary question** If there is no such option, does someone know how I can make it look right? Note that it only happens immediately after a namespace.

My current cinoptions is `cinoptions=:0,g0,=1s,(1s,N-s`

Comment: Interesting question! This seems to be related to `cinoptions=N-s`, since I seem to be able to reproduce it with that line alone (on a `*.cpp` file, `ft=cpp`, `'cindent'` enabled.) (See [`:help cino-N`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cino-N) for help on that option.) I don't think there's a way to get Vim to tell why it's indenting a line the way it is. I'd still like to have an explanation for this one, maybe someone here will be able to explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
" tell which cinoption take effect for current line
com! WhichCinoption call s:which_cinoption()

function s:which_cinoption() abort

  " test if cindent take effect
  if !empty(&indentexpr)
    echo "'indentexpr' exists, it overrides 'cindent'."
    return
  endif

  if !&cindent
    echo "'cindent' is currently disabled."
    return
  endif

  " test cinoption one by one

  " copied from :h cino- <ctrl-a> in vim8.2 1-677
  let opts = ['#','(',')','+','/',':','=','>','^','{','}','C','E','J','L','M',
        \ 'N','U','W','b','c','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','p','t',
        \ 'u','w','*']

  let indent = cindent(line('.'))
  let results = []
  let cinopt = &l:cinoptions

  for opt in opts
    try

      " test it with 8s, it should be big enough to make difference
      exe printf('setlocal cinoptions+=%s8s', opt)
      if indent != cindent(line('.'))
        let results += [opt]
      endif

    catch /.*/
      echom 'failed to test ' . opt
      echom 'internal error : ' . v:exception
    finally
      let &l:cinoptions = cinopt
    endtry
  endfor

  echohl Macro
  echom join(results)
  echohl None
endfunction
```

Test struct one:

```
WhichCinoption
--------
+
```

Comment: Thanks @dedowsdi! This was extremely useful! I built on your answer, adapted the script to calculate the effect on indentation of *each* line and generated them for the C++ snippet both with `cindent=` (empty) and `cindent=N-s` which is the one triggering the odd effect. My results are [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25338/18609). I still don't understand exactly what is triggering that odd behavior, but at least now it's very visible which `cinoptions` are affecting which line, which is what was asked! Very clever approach. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

This is `:h cino-+`.

It looks like `get_c_indent()` (from `src/cindent.c`) doesn't know about `template` and treats it like an ordinary expression split over several lines (here `namespace` serves as "a function" from `:h cino-+`).

The relevant piece of code from `src/cindent.c` is

```
2831 else if (lookfor == LOOKFOR_UNTERM)
2832 {
2833     if (cont_amount > 0)
2834         amount = cont_amount;
2835     else
2836         amount += ind_continuation;
2837 }
```

However, as far as I can tell, it's not really a bug but rather "a missing functionality".

Comment: Yes, continuation lines which defaults to shiftwidth likely explain why `struct` will be indented after `template`, but how come this only affects `struct One` and doesn't affect `struct Two`? If you have empty `cinoptions=` then both will be indented, but the whole block inside the namespace will be indented too, which I guess is the part `N-s` is trying to correct...

Comment: Yeah, so maybe also adding `cinoptions=+0` is a way to work around this and get exactly the result as expected. That would have a side effect inside functions though, not sure that's really desirable... In any case, I still can't explain why `struct One` and `struct Two` are different here, that's the part that's been irking me the most.

Comment: @filbranden Complete guess, but I reckon  it’s because the first struct comes after the initial opening `{`, but the second one comes after the *closing* `}` from the first struct, which resets the “current” indentation level.

Comment: @filbranden This is because of the closing brace in the first column: Vim believes that `struct Two` is on the global level, not inside "function".

Answer (score 2):

[@dedoswdi's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25204/18609) was extremely helpful!

I adapted it somewhat to produce the result for *each* line on the buffer. My adapted script can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/filbranden/5b92a445a09db86ba9681270fabcfe62).

After applying it to the original C++ code, I got the results with both `cinoptions=` (none of them set) and `cinoptions=N-s` (which triggers the odd behavior with the second `struct`.)

Here are the results with `cinoptions=` (empty):

```
       | namespace
f      | {
> ^ N  | 
> ^ N  |         template 
+      |                 struct One // This is the odd line
{ N    |                 {
/ > {  |                         // impl details
}      |                 };
N      | 
N      |         template 
+      |                 struct Two
{      |                 {
/ > {  |                         // impl details
}      |                 }
       | 
}      | }
```

And with `cinoptions=N-s`:

```
       | namespace
f      | {
> ^ N  | 
> ^ N  | template 
+      |         struct One // This is the odd line
{ N    | {
/ > ^  |         // impl details
}      | };
       | 
       | template 
       | struct Two
f      | {
/ > ^  |         // impl details
}      | }
       | 
       | }
```

So it's still unclear to me why the `N` is missing from the second template and why the `+` is missing from the second `struct`, but at least now it's *very* visible!

I guess this definitely answers the "Is it possible to get the rule (`cinoptions`) that govern the indentation for a specific line in vim?" question!